# UITextView how to keep cursor above keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a ViewController with UITextView taking up the whole view, with a navigation bar on top. Almost like Apple's "Notes" app. What I'm trying to achieve is to keep the textview's cursor visible when editing start, or when editing.

I was able to get the cursor's `CGPoint`, but I'm having difficult time calculating the scroll point. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

When textview starts editing

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification {

    // Keyboard
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect keyPadFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow convertRect:[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue] fromView:self.view];
    CGSize keyboardSize = keyPadFrame.size;
    kbSize = keyboardSize;

    [self scrollToCursor];
}
```

When textview is editing

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    // Scroll to cursor
    [self scrollToCursor];
}
```

Scroll to cursor method

```
- (void)scrollToCursor {
    // View
    CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect visibleViewBounds = CGRectMake(viewBounds.origin.x,
                                          viewBounds.origin.y + (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height),
                                          viewBounds.size.width,
                                          viewBounds.size.height - (kbSize.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height));

    // TextView
    CGPoint textViewOrigin = [self.view convertRect:self.noteTextView.frame fromView:self.noteTextView.superview].origin;

    // Cursor
    CGPoint textViewCursor = [self.noteTextView caretRectForPosition:self.noteTextView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
    CGPoint cursorPoint = CGPointMake((textViewCursor.x + textViewOrigin.x), (textViewCursor.y - self.noteTextView.contentOffset.y));

    // Scroll to point
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(visibleViewBounds, CGPointMake(cursorPoint.x, cursorPoint.y + 25/*25 for cursor's height*/))) {
        [self.noteTextView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)/*How to calculate??*/ animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: You know the height of the keyboard, and you can get the size of the screen. If you have the CGPoint of the cursor. you can add that y to the height of the keyboard (plus any padding) and take that away from the height of the screen. That gives you the y value to scroll to.

Comment: @Siiss Thanks for your reply! Would you mind posting an answer with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not tested at all, but would be my first attempt at it.

Get the keyboard height by listening to the KeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification

```
CGRect keyboardFrame;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
- (void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];
}
```

That will give you the keyboard height.

Then get the screen height:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;  
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

Then if you know the CGPoint of the cursor, do something like this:

```
CGFloat keyboardTop = (screenHeight - (keyboardFrame.size.height + <padding if you want it>));
if (currentCursorPosition.y > keyboardTop)
{
 [self.noteTextView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (cursorPoint.y - (viewBounds.size.height - kbSize.height)) + self.noteTextView.contentOffset.y + 25);
}
```

Ideally this should keep the cursor at the top of the keyboard and then scroll as you move the cursor down.

Comment: hmm... I made the scroll point to `CGPointMake(0, cursorPoint.y - (viewBounds.size.height - kbSize.height))` but it's not working properly. Sometimes it scrolls just a little bit, and sometimes it scrolls more than it should be... I'm not sure where went wrong :(

Comment: Ok, I finally got it to work. It was missing textview's contentOffSet. I did `CGPointMake(0, (cursorPoint.y - (viewBounds.size.height - kbSize.height)) + self.noteTextView.contentOffset.y + 25)`. Can you update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure can. Great that you got it working, and thanks for sharing the solution!

Answer (score 1):

For your sanity, just use a library.

Here is a good one: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Carthage:

> github "hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager"

CocoaPods:

> pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '6.3.0'

or

> pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '3.3.7' #iOS7